# Can I prevent the horizontal seams from showing or allowing in excessive moisture when installing T1-11 siding?

Tags: siding

I'm building a 4x8 henhouse with 5 foot high walls and I'm planning to use T1-11 siding. I could obviously buy 6 sheets of 4x8 T1-11 for the siding, but the total wall coverage is going to only be 30 square feet minus the door cutout. So I should be able to get away with using only 4 sheets of 4x8 T1-11 if I am able to stack multiple partial sheets to cover a 5 foot high wall. My question is whether it is possible to do so without the horizontal seams showing or excessive moisture coming in.

Comment: I know T1-11 is available in 9' sheets, It can be found in 10' lengths too. I have bought it from the local building supply, NOT the big box store. It will most likely be an order item

Comment: If you can make all your cuts at an even height, you can run a simple piece of trim to hide the seam.

Comment: @jack yes it can be purchased in 10’s it was not a special order for a shop I did for a friend a few years back. The extra cost per sheet would be worth in and not trying to scab together.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you don’t see T1-11 scabbed in is because you have to use Z flange to keep moisture out. Z flange is a metal flange that mounts behind comes out and goes over the lower sheet in a z shape. This prevents water from getting in it will seal but is obvious.

Comment: It's only obvious if you don't hid it behind a piece of trim!

Comment: Trim over Z flash would be a disaster on t1-11 it would hold the moisture in the channels.